# How to insert row to first place in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have question, I want to insert new row to db (mysql) using php and I need to add it to first place in table, but it comes to last position.

I need to short it like this:

3

2

1

but it shorts like

1

2

3

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot, Stepan

Comment: what about ORDER BY in mysql?

Comment: The order of tuples in a MySQL database is not guaranteed, you need to use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Whenever you select, just order by your key descending. It helps to have an auto increment key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using an incremental ID as the unique key, you can do:

```
order by id desc
```

if not, you can add a column to the DB called "created" which would be a datetime that you set to NOW() when you create the row. Then you would do:

```
order by created desc
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL databases do not guarantee an order, unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you have an identifier column, then you can do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id DESC
```